# Spring 3.2.5 returns "406 Not Acceptable" if path ends with ".xml"

Tags: java, xml, spring

I've looked at every other "406 not acceptable" question on Spring, I have not found an answer.

What I'd like to do is serve an XML file.

So I figured I'd access it like this:

```
 http://something.something.com/something/wp7.xml
```

It returns "406 Not Acceptable"

But it gets a bit odd. The code responsible for handling this is the following:

```
@Controller
public class FileController {
    @Autowired
    ApplicationConfiguration appConfig;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/something/{platform:.+}", produces = {"text/xml;charset=UTF-8"})
    public ResponseEntity<String> processRequest(@PathVariable("platform") String platform)
            throws Exception {
        try {
            String xml_path = appConfig.get(getXMLConfigKey(platform));
            File file = new File(ApplicationConfiguration.BASE_CONFIG_DIR + File.separator + xml_path);
            if (!file.exists()) {
                throw new Exception("The file [" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "] does not exist!");
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(IOUtils.toString(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"), HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("An error occurred while serving file", e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

It's odd because:

1.) I'm serving XML responses exactly like this everywhere else, and it works

2.) It works if I use any of these:

```
 http://something.something.com/something/wp7
```

or

```
 http://something.something.com/something/wp7.xm
```

or

```
 http://something.something.com/something/wp7.xmldfg
```

It literally works for everything **except** for "xml" at the end. Then it gives 406.

I don't understand what is happening. I don't even know where to look.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestmapping-suffix-pattern-match

Comment: "*I'm serving XML responses exactly like this everywhere else, and it works*" .. You mean you are using same approach like `@RequestMapping(value = "/something/{platform:.+}", produces = {"text/xml;charset=UTF-8"})` elsewhere to serve XML and it works, and only for this particular method it doesn't ?? I am asking because if so then it cannot be XML configuration issue, so we can look for other options ..

Comment: Also, can you provide your Spring web app configuration file ..

Comment: @JBNizet has linked the section of the documentation you need to read.  I'll vote it if you add an answer with an explanation JB.

Comment: Me too @jgitter. Voted for JB's comment for now ..

Comment: Feel free to answer. I'm not in the mood of copy and pasting documentation.

Comment: @hagrawal well technically I'm sending back files in this fashion elsewhere, and it works for `.jpg` files (that is `byte[]` though in its response entity) for example. It even works for `.json`. But `.xml` gives 406. There is **nothing** relevant in the config files in this regard, it's just a datasource and some irrelevant beans and a cron trigger.